# dynamic array as type in delphi/pascal object

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a unit in which there are multiple variables that has to be same sized vectors.

However I do not know the length of this array before i parse the file.

So I want to have a dynamic array that is "global" for the whole unit and then i can

The code below shows the issue as well as the solution I have now. The solution I have now is to assign a maximum value to be the length of the array.

```
unit xyz;
interface 

uses
abc

const
maxval=50;

type
vectorofdouble = [1...maxval] of double;  // I want to change this to dynamic array

type
  T_xyz = object

  public
    NP: integer;
  private
    var1: vectorofdouble;        
    var2: vectorofdouble;        
   public
    number: integer;       
    var3: vectorofdouble; 

  private
    procedure Create();
    function func1(etc): integer;
  public
    procedure ReadFile(const FileName, inputs: string);
  end;

implementation
procedure T_xyz.ReadFile();
////////
Read(F,np)
  //SetLength(vectorofdouble, np) // DOES NOT WORK
  for i := 0 to maxval // I DONT WANT TO LOOP UP TO MAXVAL
  begin
    var1[i] := 0
  end;

procedure T_xyz.func1(etc);
////////
do stuff
  for i := 0 to maxval // I DONT WANT TO LOOP UP TO MAXVAL
  begin
    var2[i] := 0
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @Brian as soon as i change from 
vectorofdouble = [1...maxval] of double; to vectorofdouble= array of double; i can not really access to vectorofdouble any where in the code setlength gives error

Comment: You need to pass the array rather than the type to `SetLength`. So, for instance, `SetLength(var1, ...)`. By the way, what does **OFlex** stand for?

Comment: Delphi 10.3 Rio. If I use "vectorofdouble= array of double;" under the type (see above) and f.e add a SetLength(vectorofdouble,10); in any function [dcc32 Error] filename.pas(438): E2029 '(' expected but ',' found

Comment: My comment explains what is wrong

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is the main code i deal with the example above is just a dummy. SetLength(var1, ...) works fine however i have 30 variables that "inherit" from vectorofdouble var1, var2 varxxx. The code above allows it to be allocated once instead of for each variable is there a method

Comment: If you want to use a dynamic array, then you need to allocate it. No shortcut. I'm still curious as to what **OFlex** is mind you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is a tool for wind turbine calculations. which I assume you are familiar with?

Comment: Is it OrcaFlex?

Comment: "O" stands for the object in general context as far as I know. It is not OrcaFlex

Comment: Interesting. OrcaFlex is also used for wind turbine calculations. Coincidence!

Comment: is it coded in Delphi/Pascal why? is it open-source ?

Comment: It's my program, that's why I am curious

Comment: ok i am new to pascal. this is "normal" flex for aeroelastic simulations.

Comment: Is it FLEX5 from the Technical University of Denmark?

Comment: yes.   that is the one

Comment: i am a little bit reluctant to accept your answer for no shortcut. Then is this the only way to introduce an allocatable to multiple variables in pascal?

Comment: on top of that ""vectorofdouble = [1...maxval] of double;"" index starts from 1 and the dynamic arrays will start from 0 so all the loops that start from 1 have to be changed

Comment: `SetLength` is the only way to allocate dynamic arrays. And it operates on a single variable at a time. You could put the dynamic arrays into an array and loop over them, not sure if that helps. And yeah, you may need to change your array indices. One options is to allocate lengths of 1 + N and use 1 .. N, ignoring item 0. But that's just storing up pain for the future. Embrace zero based

Comment: You can also use pointer instead of array,see https://zhuchengyang0207.github.io/2019/03/18/memory/  or   https://zhuchengyang0207.github.io/2019/03/18/vector/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a [**dynamic array**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) instead of a [**fixed-length array**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Arrays). You do that by using

`array of <Type>`

instead of

`array[<Low>..<High>] of <Type>`

Then `SetLength()` will work, but you need to pass it a dynamic array *variable* instead of a *type*.

Try this:

```pascal
unit xyz;

interface

uses
  abc;

type
  vectorofdouble = array of double;

type
  T_xyz = object
  public
    NP: integer;
  private
    var1: vectorofdouble;
    var2: vectorofdouble;
  public
    number: integer;
    var3: vectorofdouble;
  private
    procedure Create();
    function func1(etc): integer;
  public
    procedure ReadFile(const FileName, inputs: string);
  end;

implementation

procedure T_xyz.ReadFile();
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Read(F, NP);
  SetLength(var1, NP);
  for i := 0 to NP-1 do
  begin
    var1[i] := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure T_xyz.func1(etc);
begin
  for i := Low(var2) to High(var2) do
  begin
    var2[i] := 0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: i am not sure to answer this answer because : var2 is missing a setlength(var2,Np) argument which can be misleading as if it is enough to allocate var1 only.

Answer (score -1):

You must pass the array to `SetLength` rather than the type. So instead of

```
SetLength(vectorofdouble, np)
```

you must use

```
SetLength(var1, np)
```